Trying to have a p5.js sketch in a Cargo 3 website?
Trying two ways to have a p5.js element in my Cargo 3 site and I seem to keep hitting a different set of problems either way I set it up.

Way 1 is placing it directly in the html editor –
Way 2 is creating an html file and placing it as an iframe.

Here's what I'm working with:
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
<script> let cols; let rows;
let spacing = 30;
let size = [];
let scl = 0.1;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  cols = width/spacing;
  rows = height/spacing;
}

function draw() {
  background('#F33A00');
  
  for (let i=0; i<cols; i++){
    size[i] = [];
    for (let j=0; j<rows; j++){
      size[i][j] = (dist(mouseX, mouseY, spacing/2 + i*spacing, spacing/2 + j*spacing))*scl;
    }
  }
  
  for (let i=0; i<cols; i++){
    for (let j=0; j<rows; j++){
      //noStroke();
      fill(255);
    rect(spacing/2 + i*spacing, spacing/2 + j*spacing, size[i][j], size[i][j]);
  }
  }
}
</script>

It works perfectly until I publish the site or refresh the page, in which case I come back to it looking like this.
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script><!--<script> let cols; let rows;
let spacing = 30;
let size = [];
let scl = 0.1;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  cols = width/spacing;
  rows = height/spacing;
}

function draw() {
  background('#F33A00');
  
  for (let i=0; i<cols; i++){
    size[i] = [];
    for (let j=0; j<rows; j++){
      size[i][j] = (dist(mouseX, mouseY, spacing/2 + i*spacing, spacing/2 + j*spacing))*scl;
    }
  }
  
  for (let i=0; i<cols; i++){
    for (let j=0; j<rows; j++){
      //noStroke();
      fill(255);
    rect(spacing/2 + i*spacing, spacing/2 + j*spacing, size[i][j], size[i][j]);
  }
  }
}
</script>-->

Alternatively, I've saved that as a .html file and tried this:
<iframe class="p5" src="https://files.cargocollective.com/c11111/index.html" style="position:fixed; top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;" >
</iframe>

I've tried a good handful of variations on the iframe version and have gotten at best my sketch as a 400px tall block in the center of the page with massive margins, and at worst nothing at all.
What's going on here? Or do I have to host this somewhere that isn't cargo if I want it to work?

I added a cargo tag - please update that if that is not your "cargo" here to put the correct on in as a tag
